# Deploying .net 4 apps on .net 2 machines

Tags: .net, deployment, runtime

Our organisation only runs .net 2.0 on desktops.  It would be nice to upgrade all machines to .net 4.0, but that is not going to happen.
I wish to use .net 4.0 features.

Is there a way to statically link .net 4.0 runtime libraries into my .net 4.0 executables so they will run on a .net 2.0 environment?

Comment: Not in any way that will ever be supportable..

Comment: Which .net 4.0 features?

Comment: Probably nothing I can't find a work around for, but in general, it would be great to statically link

Comment: Doubt it in Windows without cygwin, but mono? http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono

Answer (score 2):

Just in case Marc's comment wasn't explicit enough: no way in hell.  The assembly metadata format was changed in .NET 4.0, the 2.0 CLR doesn't know how to read it.  You got the 2.0 version of the CLR running in any .NET version between 2.0 RTM and 3.5 SP1.

It is trivial to fix with a Setup project, but it certainly does get in the way of staff that takes the "I like what I know" attitude.  Breaking through that egg shell is a political problem, not a programming problem.  Good luck doing the damage.