# Including .Net 4 libraries to run on machines with .Net 2

Tags: .net, deployment

If I include all the libraries a project refers to, would the compiled application be able to run in an environment which doesn't have the required .NET Framework installed?

To be more precise, if I develop using .Net 4.0 features, would the application be able to run on a system which only has .Net 2.0 installed if I include the referenced libraries (i.e. copy them next to the executable)?

I did read this question [Deploying .net 4 apps on .net 2 machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128871/deploying-net-4-apps-on-net-2-machines), but I'm not sure of the answer because other users say that you can also redistribute the .NET runtime with your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No,   .NET 4 works on a new runtime.  It's one of the big changes that came along with .NET 4

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you *can* run on a machine without .NET 4 installed if you use a third-party tool to statically link the portions of the .NET 4 runtime that your app requires.

One such app is the [RustemSoft .NET Linker](http://www.rustemsoft.com/net_link_dll.htm)

Comment: Thank you. I gave it a try, but it says `Total 4 Referenced Assemblies / 0 Assemblies to be linked` and it doesn't let me do any linking. What does that mean?

Comment: It has been ages since I used them, so I'm not sure about the message.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a product called Xenocode PostBuild which could take a managed application and all of it's dependencies and encapsulate it as a native EXE.  Xenocode is now Spoon and they have a product called [Virtual Application Studio](http://spoon.net/studio/). I haven't used it but I think this is about what you'd need to do what you are trying to do.